# I can't understand what means this line of code

Tags: vb.net

I am reading an old code written with vb and I can not understand what means this line of code

```
CType(Cache("tabl"), Array)(CInt(Cache("lg")), 0) = myValue
```

Any help please?

Comment: For a better answer, please show us the declaration of Cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is setting a multidimensional array, using values obtained from `Cache` object.

A more readable code could be something like this:

```
Dim yourArray as Array = CType(Cache("tabl"), Array)
Dim intPosition as Integer = CInt(Cache("lg"))

yourArray(intPosition, 0) = myValue
```

Comment: +1. It's always easier to explain code by breaking it down into multiple statements.

Answer (score 3):

`CType(Cache("tabl"), Array)` --> Convert to Array

`(CInt(Cache("lg")), 0)` --> Position (So tab1 is two dimenstional Array)

`myValue` Assign the value is that position

Like

```
array1(0,0)=10
```